# Negative Gain and in a common gate FET amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain, fet, common-gate

We conducted an experiment involving frequency response in common gate FET amplifier. The results at different frequencies from 10 Hz to 1 MHz are obtained and we got a negative result in the first few frequencies. What does a negative value of gain mean, what is its effect on circuits, and what is its difference from a positive value of gain?

[image]

Comment: That helps, but brings up more questions.  What's the point of R2?  It makes no sense.  Now we see you are using a N channel JFET.  Is this a enhancement or depletion mode device?  Put another way, what conduction do you expect with gate and source at the same voltage.  How do you know the junction isn't conducting?  The biasing seems rather strange, at least if you are looking for linear operation.  A link to the FET datasheet would help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a DC blocking capacitor on both the input and the output. This will act as a impedance, the value of which will decrease with frequency:

$$Z_{cap} = -\frac{j}{\omega C} $$

Where \$\omega\$ is the angular frequency, or \$\omega = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot f\$ and \$C\$ is the capacitance in Farad.

At low frequencies, this value is very big. In other words, this means that your capacitor will act as a very large resistance, forming a voltage divider with the input of the circuit. Only at higher frequencies will this attenuation become negligible, and will the circuit be able to provide gain.

> > I want to know what does a negative value of gain means and its effect on circuits.

This depends on what unit your gain is in.

For voltage gain, we generally write

$$A_V = \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}$$

Or we can rewrite this as

$$V_{OUT} = V_{IN}\cdot A_V$$

So, if we have a gain of 10, the output voltage is ten times the input voltage. If we have a gain of -10, the output voltage is the inverse of the input voltage, but the swing is 10 times larger.

So, to sum that up: If our gain is expressed in V/V, a negative gain means that our output is inverted.

However, if we are working in decibels, things change a bit. The voltage gain in decibels is defined as

$$A_{V,dB} = 20\cdot \log_{10}({A_{V}})$$

Due to the nature of how logarithms are undefined for negative arguments, we can't deal with negative gains in logarithms. Instead, we take the absolute value, and then plug that in. So, regardless of us having a voltage gain of 10 or -10, it will both turn into 20 dB. 0 dB gain means our input and output signals are identical. A negative gain in dB will mean our output signal is weaker than our input signal - in other words, we attenuated the signal.

Comment: Gain is output amplitude divided by input amplitude (or RMS or peak-to-peak), so it’s always positive. Gain in dB will be negative if the gain is fractional.